# How to set zoom level of camera using AVFoundation framework in IOS?

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation

I am developing a custom camera in which the camera is set to the Image Capture mode. I need to increase the zoom level of camera preview according to the app requirements. The preview currently being displayed is perfect I just need to increase the zoom-out in current preview. I searched over internet but didn't find any solution. Please tell me how can I do this. I am attaching the example image for better understanding. first image is of my camera app and second image is of **Scanner Pro** app which shows view with more covered area while I focus both the apps for the same object on the same distance. My camera don't have any space but the Scanner camera has spacing all over the image. Both the camera are on the same distance from the paper.

[image]

Comment: Apple Officials https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-SW111

Answer (score 0):

i don't know whether you still need this answer. Probably not, but still for you and everyone else looking out:

When you set the Session Preset, try using `SessionPresetPhoto`for the device object. This should resolve the weird zoom issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your preview view is probably spilling over the edge of the screen. Make sure it is a 4:3 aspect ratio and that it doesn’t overflow your screen edges. With that you should see more of your image.